# android app crashes while timer loop

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm new here and noob as well. I started learning Java and Android by making my first simple app.

I want to do the time loop to do some function every 1 sec.
I have this:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        imV.setImageResource(stageArray.getResourceId(step, -1));
        Log.d("MyApp","I am here");
        step ++;
    }
},0,1000);
```

It's in my `init()` function.
After I run this on my device, the app crashes.
When I delete the `imV.setImageRes...` line it runs, but I don't get log notifications.
The step value is changing.
Something similiar is happening when I use a Handler.

So why my app crash?
Why cannot I see any log.d from this loop?
Are there better ways to do time loop to make simple changes?

Comment: Since it crashes on the line before Log.d you won't see it, what is exactly the exception thrown, check in the DDMS logs

Comment: show your logcat statement.., should  be problem with stageArray

Comment: ok, i updated Android Studio version, downloaded more tools and it works. Maybe there were errors while building new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app has crashed because you **access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread** when you call *imV.setImageResource(stageArray.getResourceId(step, -1));*. So that, exception has occurred. You must set image for imageview in UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imV.setImageResource(stageArray.getResourceId(step, -1));
                }
            });
```

Or simple solution with **CountDownTimer**

```
new CountDownTimer(totalStep * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            step = millisUntilFinished/1000;
            imV.setImageResource(_yourResID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("Finish", "Done");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I updated version of Android Studio and downloaded more tools and now is ok. Time to read more about threads and communication